# How to restrict website users from seeing other user profiles?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I created some users for my website in Django and i want each user to access only his own profile page .

The template for the user profile page is fetched through a CBV Detail View called `UserDetailView` attached to a URL containing the user's  and the page is loading only after authentication .( user logged in). So far so good.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from basicapp import views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

app_name='basicapp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^user_list/',views.UserView.as_view(),name='user_list'),
    url(r'^course_list/',views.CourseView.as_view(),name='course_list'),
    url(r'^user_detail/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.UserDetailView.as_view(),name='user_detail'),    
   

]
```

The problem is after I login and get the user detail page : If I manually change the `<pk>` in the URL I get other user profile pages loaded. I don't want that to happen .

For ex, the URL for the logged in user profile is :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/user_detail/1/

With the user already logged in i manually change the URL to :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/user_detail/2/

and it works. It should retrict me or show me an error message

I tried using `LoginRequiredMixin`

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name='user_detail'
    model=models.User
    template_name='basicapp/user_detail.html'
    raise_exception = True  # Raise exception when no access instead of redirect
    permission_denied_message = "This page dows not exist."
```

and I also tried using`method_decorator` :

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name='user_detail'
    model=models.User
    template_name='basicapp/user_detail.html'
    raise_exception = True  # Raise exception when no access instead of redirect
    permission_denied_message = "This page dows not exist."
```

but it doesn't seem to work . I restarted the server.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The `LoginRequiredMixin` will ensure that you can only see the page if you are logged in, but that does not mean you have to be that user.

However if you can only see your own profile, it does not make much sense to add a primary key in the `url` anyway, you can just define the url as:

```
url(r'^user_detail/$', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
```

In the view you then return the logged in user for the [**`.get_object()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object):

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name='user_detail'
    model=models.User
    template_name='basicapp/user_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user
```

Or you can restrict users by filtering the queryset:

```
path('^user_detail/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
```

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name='user_detail'
    model=models.User
    template_name='basicapp/user_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return qs
```

Comment: Good. So far , the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/basicapp/user_profile/ works but would still need the URL with the pk because being an admin i want to manage all the profiles under the admin username. Somehow i want to restrict other users from accesing the the URL containing pk.

Comment: @VoicuMirel: shouldn't this be `/user_detail`? (instead of `/user_profile`)?

Comment: @VoicuMirel: then you can filter the `QuerySet` with `.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)`.

Comment: i kept the old url defined because i need it  and added a new one called user_profile to see that it works and it does but i want to know if there is a way i can restrict the view from other users that access the forbiden URL   ` url(r'^user_detail/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.UserDetailView.as_view(),name='user_detail') `
    url(r'^user_profile/$', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),'

Comment: @VoicuMirel: please do not use `[-\w]+`, this means it can also accept `foo-4bar`, and `blabla` as `pk` for the user.

Comment: @VoicuMirel: the second one should return a 404 if the user is not a superuser and tries to visit a profile page of a different user.

Comment: Second method works perfectly as described . If i am not a superuser I get 404. With superuser i can manually access other user profiles. Thank You